# Gedmo\Translatable ignoring default locale that is set in config

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've decided to install `"gedmo/doctrine-extensions"` on Symfony to use `Translatable`.

It works fine, except that listener is ignoring default locale I've specified, always falling back to `en_US`.

Translatable is plugged in as service:

```
#config.yml
services:
    gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ ru ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ true ] ]
```

And when I try to `find()` object in database it always fetches `en_US` instead of `ru`:

```
$test = $em->find('Vendor\Entity\Test', 1);
//outputs row with 'locale' = "en_US" from `ext_translations_test` table
```

Only if I specify language directly, like:

```
$test->setTranslatableLocale('ru');
$em->refresh($test);
```

It gives desired translation.

Is there any way to set default locale that will work?

**UPDATE**

Adding another call function in `config.yml` fixed the problem, altough now I'm not quite sure what `setDefaultLocale()` function actually does, as `Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::$defaultLocale` property provided with a most horrid commentary I've ever seen. Will try to find more...

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ ru ] ]
            - [ setTranslatableLocale, [ ru ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ true ] ]
```

Comment: try `- [ setDefaultLocale, [ "ru" ] ]` with ru in quotes

Comment: @Chausser, negative. Same result.

Comment: what version of doctrine extensions are you using?

Comment: Are you importing the config file into the main config?

Comment: this approach allow you only hardcoding locale parameter. If you'll try to get locale from request you'll need to implement `DoctrineExtensionListener` as @Chausser described below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md

> Note: if you noticed, there's Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\DoctrineExtensionListener you will need to create this listener class if you use loggable or translatable behaviors. This listener will set the locale used from request and username to loggable. So, to finish the setup create Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\DoctrineExtensionListener

Make sure you have setup the kernel listener as well.

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class DoctrineExtensionListener implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onLateKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $translatable = $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.translatable');
        $translatable->setTranslatableLocale($event->getRequest()->getLocale());
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context', ContainerInterface::NULL_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE);
        if (null !== $securityContext && null !== $securityContext->getToken() && $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            $loggable = $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.loggable');
            $loggable->setUsername($securityContext->getToken()->getUsername());
        }
    }
}
```

And add the following to your config file:

```
services:
    extension.listener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\DoctrineExtensionListener
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
        tags:
            # translatable sets locale after router processing
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onLateKernelRequest, priority: -10 }
            # loggable hooks user username if one is in security context
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Comment: Actually, after looking in the `Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener` class I've added another call function in `config.yml` and it kind of fixed the problem. Your answer gave me an idea, see update. Thank you!

Comment: @Chausser, thanks for detailed answer, it helped me a lot. Btw, you can use symfony's `ContainerAwareTrait` to avoid declaration of `container` field and `setContainer` method.

Comment: on Symfony 5 setting locale  `onLateKernelRequest` did not work. When set locale on `onKernelRequest` event it worked. Otherwise, I kept getting default translation